# A doubt in the proof that there square root of a positive self-adjoint operator

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-explanation, solution-verification, spectral-theory

I am reading a nice proof that there is only one square root of a positive self-adjoint operator using spectral measures in the book of Konrad Schmudgen: Unbounded Self-adjoint Operators on Hilbert Space.
I was confused only in the two parts of red that I marked, in the first, wouldn't it be $ = $ instead of the inclusion? Is the second part really necessary? Doesn't equality follow from before? The figure below also follows the Theorem used

[image]

Comment: The domain of $B^2$ is the preimage of the domain of $B$ under $B$, i.e. $$\mathcal{D}(B^2) = \{ x \in \mathcal{D}(B) : Bx \in \mathcal{D}(B)\}\,.$$ It's not immediately clear that that is all of $\mathcal{D}(B)$.

Comment: I understand. So the correct thing is also to use item 4) of proposition $5.9$ to see that $ B $ is adjoint-self to conclude that $B^2$ is adjoint-self? To conclude that $\mathcal{D}(B^2) = \mathcal{D}(B)$?

Comment: Point 6) gives you $A = \overline{B^2}$. Self-adjointness gives you closedness, hence $A = B^2$. For the self-adjointness, point 4) seems to be the natural argument, but perhaps Schmudgen considered that too obvious to mention explicitly.

Comment: right, but that $B^2$ is self-adjoint followed by 4) or the equality itself found?

Comment: Hm, actually, is it clear that the square of an *unbounded* self-adjoint operator is self-adjoint? At the moment, I don't see an obvious argument.

Comment: I thought I understood correctly, but now I realized that I didn't. So why is $B^2$ adjoint-self? is why is $A$ adjoint-self?

Comment: I've never done much with unbounded operators, so I'm not completely at home with them. I'm pretty sure that $B^2$ is self-adjoint, and there should be a relatively straightforward argument for that. But right now, I don't see it.

Comment: Ok, i will try to look for this result in some book. But, thank you very much for your help, it was very useful.

Comment: @DanielFischer you are correct, the result is in Theorem 2.2 here https://arxiv.org/pdf/1403.5914.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the argument Schmüdgen had in mind was the following. First note that $T^\ast T$ is self-adjoint for every closed densely defined $T$ (Proposition 3.18). Thus $B^2$ in the question is self-adjoint. Moreover, self-adjoint operators cannot have proper self-adjoint extensions: If $S$ and $T$ are self-adjoint and $S\subseteq T$, then $T=T^\ast\subseteq S^\ast=S$, hence $S=T$. I'm pretty sure this is also mentioned somewhere in the book. In the situation of the question that means that $B^2$ must be equal to $A$, since the latter is a self-adjoint extension of the former.