# If $P$ is self-adjoint and $P^2$ is a projection, when is $P$ a projection?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $P:H \to H$ a bounded linear operator.

I am aware that if $P$ is self-adjoint and idempotent then it's a (orthogonal) projection.

My question is: if $P$ is self-adjoint and $P^2$ is a projection, is $P$ necessarily a projection? If not always, when?

Definitions:

1. $P$ is self-adjoint $:\iff$ $P = P^*$, that is, $\langle Px, y \rangle = \langle x, P^*y \rangle \forall x,y \in H$ (if $H$ is a complex Hilbert space than it suffices to check this for $y=x$)
2. $P$ is idempotent $:\iff$ $P = P^2$

My initial thoughts:

- maybe not in general. consider $H = \mathbb{R}^2$ with $P$ the left-shift operator ($P$ defined by the matrix $((0, 0)^T, (1, 0)^T)$). Then $P^2$ projects everything to zero, but $P$ is not a projection.
- so: maybe this needs stricter assumptions.

  - must $P^2 \ne 0$?
  - maybe the space must be infinite dimensional?

Comment: Your example is not self-adjoint. You have $T(x,y)=(y,0)$. The adjoint is $T^*(x,y) = (0,x)$.

Comment: But $-I$ is self-adjoint, and the square is projection, but it itself is not. If you want one with non-trivial kernel, map the first basis vector to minus itself, all others to $\mathbf{0}$.

Comment: In finite dimension, slef-adjoint means diagonalizable and all eigenvalues are real. Projection means diagonalizable and all eigenvalues are either $0$ or $1$. If $P^2$ is a projection then the eigenvalues of $P$ will be either $0$, $1$, or $-1$, so you get a projection exactly when $-1$ is not an eigenvalue. So $P$ will be itself a projection if and only if it is positive semidefinite

Comment: By the spectral theorem, the conclusion of @ArturoMagidin's last comment also holds for infinite-dimensional Hilbert spaces.

Comment: thank you so much, everyone! this makes sense. i really appreciate these explanations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the comments gave the answer already I, nonetheless, want to give a proof which does not rely on eigenvalues or diagonalizability, thus settling your question for *arbitrary* Hilbert spaces. A corollary of the following theorem is that any $P\in\mathcal B(\mathcal H)$ self-adjoint with $P^2=P^4$ is a projection if and only if $P\geq 0$; however, I prefer the version below because it shifts the assumptions on $P$ to the statement.

> **Theorem.** Let a Hilbert space $\mathcal H$ as well as $P\in\mathcal B(\mathcal H)$ be given. Then $P$ is an [orthogonal projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(linear_algebra)#Orthogonal_projections) if and only if $P$ is positive semi-definite and satisfies $P^2=P^4$.

NB: For arbitrary Hilbert spaces "positive semi-definite" is defined as $A=A^*$ and $\langle x,Ax\rangle\geq 0$ for all $x\in\mathcal H$.
Now if $\mathcal H$ is a complex Hilbert space, then it is enough to define $A\geq 0$ as $\langle x,Ax\rangle\geq 0$ because [this automatically implies](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3060482/positive-operator-is-symmetric) that $A$ is self-adjoint.

*Proof of theorem.* "$\Rightarrow$": Let $P$ be an orthogonal projection, i.e. $P=P^2=P^*P$. Obviously $P^4=(P^2)(P^2)=PP=P^2$. Moreover $\langle x,Px\rangle=\langle x,P^*Px\rangle=\langle Px,Px\rangle=\|Px\|^2\geq 0$ for all $x\in\mathcal H$, that is, $P\geq 0$ (because $P=P^*$ by assumption).

"$\Leftarrow$": Because $P\geq 0$, in particular $P$ is self-adjoint so all we have to show is $P=P^2$. Note that $P^2=P^*P\geq 0$ which implies that $P^2$ has a [unique square root](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3813145/a-doubt-in-the-proof-that-there-square-root-of-a-positive-self-adjoint-operator); (by uniqueness) this is obviously given by $P$. Analogously one sees that the square root of $P^4\geq 0$ is given by $P^2$. Again because the square root is unique we conclude$
P=\sqrt{P^2}=\sqrt{P^4}=P^2$. $\quad\square$